# Angular filter Observable object

Tags: angular

I need help filtering the json data object for only trams that are heading to a specific station. 
here is my code.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tram';
  url:string = `https://api.sl.se/api2/realtimedeparturesV4.json?key=c3fa612773d9439699d02d0d069549ce&SiteID=1555&timewindow=60`;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get(this.url).toPromise().then(data =>{
      console.log(data);
      
    });
  }
}
```

here is how my returned object :

```js
{
    "StatusCode": 0,
    "Message": null,
    "ExecutionTime": 73,
    "ResponseData": {
        "LatestUpdate": "2020-03-07T16:28:06",
        "DataAge": 35,
        "Metros": [],
        "Buses": [
            {
                "GroupOfLine": null,
                "TransportMode": "BUS",
                "LineNumber": "74",
                "Destination": "Mariatorget via Södersjukhuset",
                "JourneyDirection": 2,
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 10684,
                "StopPointNumber": 10684,
                "StopPointDesignation": null,
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:38:00",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:38:00",
                "DisplayTime": "9 min",
                "JourneyNumber": 44078,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "GroupOfLine": null,
                "TransportMode": "BUS",
                "LineNumber": "74",
                "Destination": "Sickla udde",
                "JourneyDirection": 1,
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 10684,
                "StopPointNumber": 10687,
                "StopPointDesignation": null,
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:37:00",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:38:39",
                "DisplayTime": "9 min",
                "JourneyNumber": 44111,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "GroupOfLine": null,
                "TransportMode": "BUS",
                "LineNumber": "74",
                "Destination": "Sickla udde",
                "JourneyDirection": 1,
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 10684,
                "StopPointNumber": 10687,
                "StopPointDesignation": null,
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:57:00",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:57:00",
                "DisplayTime": "28 min",
                "JourneyNumber": 44112,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "GroupOfLine": null,
                "TransportMode": "BUS",
                "LineNumber": "74",
                "Destination": "Mariatorget via Södersjukhuset",
                "JourneyDirection": 2,
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 10684,
                "StopPointNumber": 10684,
                "StopPointDesignation": null,
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:58:00",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:58:00",
                "DisplayTime": "16:58",
                "JourneyNumber": 44079,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "GroupOfLine": null,
                "TransportMode": "BUS",
                "LineNumber": "74",
                "Destination": "Sickla udde",
                "JourneyDirection": 1,
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 10684,
                "StopPointNumber": 10687,
                "StopPointDesignation": null,
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:17:00",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:17:00",
                "DisplayTime": "17:17",
                "JourneyNumber": 44113,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "GroupOfLine": null,
                "TransportMode": "BUS",
                "LineNumber": "74",
                "Destination": "Mariatorget via Södersjukhuset",
                "JourneyDirection": 2,
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 10684,
                "StopPointNumber": 10684,
                "StopPointDesignation": null,
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:18:00",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:18:00",
                "DisplayTime": "17:18",
                "JourneyNumber": 44080,
                "Deviations": null
            }
        ],
        "Trains": [],
        "Trams": [
            {
                "TransportMode": "TRAM",
                "LineNumber": "22",
                "Destination": "Sickla",
                "JourneyDirection": 2,
                "GroupOfLine": "Tvärbanan",
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointNumber": 4528,
                "StopPointDesignation": "2",
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:33:00",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:33:58",
                "DisplayTime": "5 min",
                "JourneyNumber": 21548,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "TransportMode": "TRAM",
                "LineNumber": "22",
                "Destination": "Solna station",
                "JourneyDirection": 1,
                "GroupOfLine": "Tvärbanan",
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointDesignation": "1",
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:33:30",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:35:12",
                "DisplayTime": "6 min",
                "JourneyNumber": 11627,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "TransportMode": "TRAM",
                "LineNumber": "22",
                "Destination": "Solna station",
                "JourneyDirection": 1,
                "GroupOfLine": "Tvärbanan",
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointDesignation": "1",
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:43:30",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:43:30",
                "DisplayTime": "16:43",
                "JourneyNumber": 11637,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "TransportMode": "TRAM",
                "LineNumber": "22",
                "Destination": "Sickla",
                "JourneyDirection": 2,
                "GroupOfLine": "Tvärbanan",
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointNumber": 4528,
                "StopPointDesignation": "2",
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:43:00",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:44:50",
                "DisplayTime": "16 min",
                "JourneyNumber": 21558,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "TransportMode": "TRAM",
                "LineNumber": "22",
                "Destination": "Solna station",
                "JourneyDirection": 1,
                "GroupOfLine": "Tvärbanan",
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointDesignation": "1",
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:53:30",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:53:30",
                "DisplayTime": "16:53",
                "JourneyNumber": 11647,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "TransportMode": "TRAM",
                "LineNumber": "22",
                "Destination": "Sickla",
                "JourneyDirection": 2,
                "GroupOfLine": "Tvärbanan",
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointNumber": 4528,
                "StopPointDesignation": "2",
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:53:00",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:53:59",
                "DisplayTime": "25 min",
                "JourneyNumber": 21608,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "TransportMode": "TRAM",
                "LineNumber": "22",
                "Destination": "Solna station",
                "JourneyDirection": 1,
                "GroupOfLine": "Tvärbanan",
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointDesignation": "1",
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:03:30",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:03:30",
                "DisplayTime": "17:03",
                "JourneyNumber": 11657,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "TransportMode": "TRAM",
                "LineNumber": "22",
                "Destination": "Sickla",
                "JourneyDirection": 2,
                "GroupOfLine": "Tvärbanan",
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointNumber": 4528,
                "StopPointDesignation": "2",
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:03:00",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:05:56",
                "DisplayTime": "17:03",
                "JourneyNumber": 21618,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "TransportMode": "TRAM",
                "LineNumber": "22",
                "Destination": "Solna station",
                "JourneyDirection": 1,
                "GroupOfLine": "Tvärbanan",
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointDesignation": "1",
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:13:30",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:13:30",
                "DisplayTime": "17:13",
                "JourneyNumber": 11707,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "TransportMode": "TRAM",
                "LineNumber": "22",
                "Destination": "Sickla",
                "JourneyDirection": 2,
                "GroupOfLine": "Tvärbanan",
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointNumber": 4528,
                "StopPointDesignation": "2",
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:13:00",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:14:48",
                "DisplayTime": "17:13",
                "JourneyNumber": 21628,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "TransportMode": "TRAM",
                "LineNumber": "22",
                "Destination": "Sickla",
                "JourneyDirection": 2,
                "GroupOfLine": "Tvärbanan",
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointNumber": 4528,
                "StopPointDesignation": "2",
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:23:00",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:23:00",
                "DisplayTime": "17:23",
                "JourneyNumber": 21638,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "TransportMode": "TRAM",
                "LineNumber": "22",
                "Destination": "Solna station",
                "JourneyDirection": 1,
                "GroupOfLine": "Tvärbanan",
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointDesignation": "1",
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:23:30",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:23:30",
                "DisplayTime": "17:23",
                "JourneyNumber": 11717,
                "Deviations": null
            }
        ],
        "Ships": [],
        "StopPointDeviations": []
    }
}
```

I just want to know how to filter this data to get only trams hiding to a specific city that I can specify.
here is the API documentation : https://www.trafiklab.se/node/15754/documentation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, there's no need to convert observables to promises - you're losing out on the power of RxJS by doing this.

Secondly, it's bad practice to do anything other than trivial setup in the constructor. Instead, initialise the component in `ngOnInit`.

Once you have the response data in your subscribe, you can simply use an array `filter` to get the trams you want.

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tram';
  url:string = `https://api.sl.se/api2/realtimedeparturesV4.json?key=c3fa612773d9439699d02d0d069549ce&SiteID=1555&timewindow=60`;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {    
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get(this.url).subscribe((data: any) =>{
      const trams = data.ResponseData.Trams;
      const sicklaTrams = this.filterTrams(trams, 'Sickla');
      console.log(sicklaTrams);
    });
  }

  private filterTrams(trams: any[], destination: string): any[] {
    return trams.filter(tram => tram.Destination === destination);
  }
}
```

You've not specified how the destination is provided, or whether it needs to be a case-sensitive filter. I've hard coded a destination and performed a case-sensitive comparison for the purposes of a simple example.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-54g5ah

Comment: thank you so much but I get this error : error TS2339: Property 'ResponseData' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Comment: That probably means that `ResponseData` *is* the response. Instead, try `const trams = data.Trams`. If that still doesn't work, add `console.log(data)` to see what the actual response is and work it out from there.

Comment: actually I can only access methods on data (hasOwnProperty ,toString..etc) I can't access whats inside the object

Comment: I assume what you mean is that intellisense only shows those things? Have you tried logging `data` to the console to see what properties it contains?

Comment: yes I did and its exactly what I posted in my question .

Comment: You need to tell typescript that the response type is of type `any`. I've edited my example.

Comment: And my `destination` property casing was wrong - fixed to `tram.Destination`

Answer (score 1):

The response is an object and just call it like object attributes like following. Then use filter method with the filter condition.

`myResult.ResponseData.Trams.filter(t=> t.Destination=='Solna station')`

```js
let myResult = {
    "StatusCode": 0,
    "Message": null,
    "ExecutionTime": 73,
    "ResponseData": {
        "LatestUpdate": "2020-03-07T16:28:06",
        "DataAge": 35,
        "Metros": [],
        "Buses": [
            {
                "GroupOfLine": null,
                "TransportMode": "BUS",
                "LineNumber": "74",
                "Destination": "Mariatorget via Södersjukhuset",
                "JourneyDirection": 2,
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 10684,
                "StopPointNumber": 10684,
                "StopPointDesignation": null,
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:38:00",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:38:00",
                "DisplayTime": "9 min",
                "JourneyNumber": 44078,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "GroupOfLine": null,
                "TransportMode": "BUS",
                "LineNumber": "74",
                "Destination": "Sickla udde",
                "JourneyDirection": 1,
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 10684,
                "StopPointNumber": 10687,
                "StopPointDesignation": null,
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:37:00",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:38:39",
                "DisplayTime": "9 min",
                "JourneyNumber": 44111,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "GroupOfLine": null,
                "TransportMode": "BUS",
                "LineNumber": "74",
                "Destination": "Sickla udde",
                "JourneyDirection": 1,
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 10684,
                "StopPointNumber": 10687,
                "StopPointDesignation": null,
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:57:00",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:57:00",
                "DisplayTime": "28 min",
                "JourneyNumber": 44112,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "GroupOfLine": null,
                "TransportMode": "BUS",
                "LineNumber": "74",
                "Destination": "Mariatorget via Södersjukhuset",
                "JourneyDirection": 2,
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 10684,
                "StopPointNumber": 10684,
                "StopPointDesignation": null,
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:58:00",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:58:00",
                "DisplayTime": "16:58",
                "JourneyNumber": 44079,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "GroupOfLine": null,
                "TransportMode": "BUS",
                "LineNumber": "74",
                "Destination": "Sickla udde",
                "JourneyDirection": 1,
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 10684,
                "StopPointNumber": 10687,
                "StopPointDesignation": null,
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:17:00",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:17:00",
                "DisplayTime": "17:17",
                "JourneyNumber": 44113,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "GroupOfLine": null,
                "TransportMode": "BUS",
                "LineNumber": "74",
                "Destination": "Mariatorget via Södersjukhuset",
                "JourneyDirection": 2,
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 10684,
                "StopPointNumber": 10684,
                "StopPointDesignation": null,
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:18:00",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:18:00",
                "DisplayTime": "17:18",
                "JourneyNumber": 44080,
                "Deviations": null
            }
        ],
        "Trains": [],
        "Trams": [
            {
                "TransportMode": "TRAM",
                "LineNumber": "22",
                "Destination": "Sickla",
                "JourneyDirection": 2,
                "GroupOfLine": "Tvärbanan",
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointNumber": 4528,
                "StopPointDesignation": "2",
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:33:00",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:33:58",
                "DisplayTime": "5 min",
                "JourneyNumber": 21548,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "TransportMode": "TRAM",
                "LineNumber": "22",
                "Destination": "Solna station",
                "JourneyDirection": 1,
                "GroupOfLine": "Tvärbanan",
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointDesignation": "1",
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:33:30",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:35:12",
                "DisplayTime": "6 min",
                "JourneyNumber": 11627,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "TransportMode": "TRAM",
                "LineNumber": "22",
                "Destination": "Solna station",
                "JourneyDirection": 1,
                "GroupOfLine": "Tvärbanan",
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointDesignation": "1",
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:43:30",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:43:30",
                "DisplayTime": "16:43",
                "JourneyNumber": 11637,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "TransportMode": "TRAM",
                "LineNumber": "22",
                "Destination": "Sickla",
                "JourneyDirection": 2,
                "GroupOfLine": "Tvärbanan",
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointNumber": 4528,
                "StopPointDesignation": "2",
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:43:00",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:44:50",
                "DisplayTime": "16 min",
                "JourneyNumber": 21558,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "TransportMode": "TRAM",
                "LineNumber": "22",
                "Destination": "Solna station",
                "JourneyDirection": 1,
                "GroupOfLine": "Tvärbanan",
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointDesignation": "1",
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:53:30",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:53:30",
                "DisplayTime": "16:53",
                "JourneyNumber": 11647,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "TransportMode": "TRAM",
                "LineNumber": "22",
                "Destination": "Sickla",
                "JourneyDirection": 2,
                "GroupOfLine": "Tvärbanan",
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointNumber": 4528,
                "StopPointDesignation": "2",
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:53:00",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T16:53:59",
                "DisplayTime": "25 min",
                "JourneyNumber": 21608,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "TransportMode": "TRAM",
                "LineNumber": "22",
                "Destination": "Solna station",
                "JourneyDirection": 1,
                "GroupOfLine": "Tvärbanan",
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointDesignation": "1",
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:03:30",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:03:30",
                "DisplayTime": "17:03",
                "JourneyNumber": 11657,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "TransportMode": "TRAM",
                "LineNumber": "22",
                "Destination": "Sickla",
                "JourneyDirection": 2,
                "GroupOfLine": "Tvärbanan",
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointNumber": 4528,
                "StopPointDesignation": "2",
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:03:00",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:05:56",
                "DisplayTime": "17:03",
                "JourneyNumber": 21618,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "TransportMode": "TRAM",
                "LineNumber": "22",
                "Destination": "Solna station",
                "JourneyDirection": 1,
                "GroupOfLine": "Tvärbanan",
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointDesignation": "1",
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:13:30",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:13:30",
                "DisplayTime": "17:13",
                "JourneyNumber": 11707,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "TransportMode": "TRAM",
                "LineNumber": "22",
                "Destination": "Sickla",
                "JourneyDirection": 2,
                "GroupOfLine": "Tvärbanan",
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointNumber": 4528,
                "StopPointDesignation": "2",
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:13:00",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:14:48",
                "DisplayTime": "17:13",
                "JourneyNumber": 21628,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "TransportMode": "TRAM",
                "LineNumber": "22",
                "Destination": "Sickla",
                "JourneyDirection": 2,
                "GroupOfLine": "Tvärbanan",
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointNumber": 4528,
                "StopPointDesignation": "2",
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:23:00",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:23:00",
                "DisplayTime": "17:23",
                "JourneyNumber": 21638,
                "Deviations": null
            },
            {
                "TransportMode": "TRAM",
                "LineNumber": "22",
                "Destination": "Solna station",
                "JourneyDirection": 1,
                "GroupOfLine": "Tvärbanan",
                "StopAreaName": "Mårtensdal",
                "StopAreaNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointNumber": 4527,
                "StopPointDesignation": "1",
                "TimeTabledDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:23:30",
                "ExpectedDateTime": "2020-03-07T17:23:30",
                "DisplayTime": "17:23",
                "JourneyNumber": 11717,
                "Deviations": null
            }
        ],
        "Ships": [],
        "StopPointDeviations": []
    }
}


console.log(myResult.ResponseData.Trams.filter(t=> t.Destination=='Solna station'));
```